# Shifting id values of existing rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment, alter-table

I have a table in a mysql database, in which every row has an id column with auto increment. 
The id values start at 1, and end at 639.

What I need to do is change the id column of each row, so that the count doesn't begin at 1 but at 1924.

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=1924;
```

but that doesn't seem to do what I need, it only resets the future count so that any future rows added start counting at 1924.

I need to change the *existing* ID values of *existing* rows.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why you want to do this?. You have to unload the data und reload it with changing the ID and the foreign keys if nesessary.

Comment: Because I need to move the data from this table into another table (with identical structure) in another database, whose id values are currently at 1923, so I need to shift these to avoid id conflicts. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  UPDATE myTable SET id=id+1923
```

Simple as that

Comment: But it only works if you have no foreign keys on it.